# Rename row values that duplicate within two columns but have a unique ID

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to add a number to the end of an `Area` value where it appears with more than one unique `ID` in the same year.

```
data <- data.frame(
  AREA = c("Riverview", "Riverview", "Riverview", "Lake Beach", "Lake Beach", "Lake Beach", "Lake Beach", "Lake Beach", "Lake Beach", "Oasis", "Oasis"),
  YEAR = c(2012, 2013, 2014, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2012, 2013),
  ID = c("A0", "A0", "A1", "A2", "A2", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A2", "A4", "A4")
)
```

So I want this:

```
AREA          YEAR   ID
-----------------------
Riverview     2012   A0
Riverview     2013   A0
Riverview     2014   A1
Lake Beach    2012   A2
Lake Beach    2012   A2
Lake Beach    2012   A3
Lake Beach    2013   A3   
Lake Beach    2013   A3
Lake Beach    2013   A2
Oasis         2012   A4
Oasis         2013   A4
```

To become this:

```
AREA            YEAR   ID
-------------------------
Riverview       2012   A0
Riverview       2013   A0
Riverview       2014   A1
Lake Beach 1    2012   A2
Lake Beach 1    2012   A2
Lake Beach 2    2012   A3
Lake Beach 2    2013   A3   
Lake Beach 2    2013   A3
Lake Beach 1    2013   A2
Oasis           2012   A4
Oasis           2013   A4
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
data |>
  mutate(
    AREA = case_when(
      n() > 1 ~ paste(AREA, as.integer(factor(ID))),
      .default = AREA
    ),
    .by = c(AREA, YEAR)
  )
#            AREA YEAR ID
# 1     Riverview 2012 A0
# 2     Riverview 2013 A0
# 3     Riverview 2014 A1
# 4  Lake Beach 1 2012 A2
# 5  Lake Beach 1 2012 A2
# 6  Lake Beach 2 2012 A3
# 7  Lake Beach 2 2013 A3
# 8  Lake Beach 2 2013 A3
# 9  Lake Beach 1 2013 A2
# 10        Oasis 2012 A4
# 11        Oasis 2013 A4
```

Comment: Thank you!! There is one last problem. This code also adds a number to an `AREA` value when it appears more than once in the same year with the same ID. How can I adapt your code so that `AREA` is only changed when its **ID changes** within the **same year**?

I've amended the dataset so this is visible (below). Thanks again.

Comment: data <- data.frame(
  AREA = c("Riverview", "Riverview", "Riverview", "Riverview", "Riverview", "Lake Beach", "Lake Beach", "Lake Beach", "Lake Beach", "Lake Beach", "Lake Beach", "Oasis", "Oasis"),
  YEAR = c(2012, 2013, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2012, 2013),
  ID = c("A0", "A0", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A2", "A4", "A4")
)

Comment: I think you can change `n() > 1` to `n_distinct(ID) > 1`,  but it's not super clear to me if that's what you want. It might be clearer if you edit the question (or ask a new question) with the modified input and expected output.

Comment: Your solution to use `n_distinct(ID)` instead of `n()` worked perfectly. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

A data.table option:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)
data[, AREA := if (uniqueN(ID) > 1) paste(AREA, match(ID, sort(unique(ID))) ) else AREA, 
     by = .(AREA, YEAR)]
data
#             AREA  YEAR     ID
#           <char> <num> <char>
#  1:    Riverview  2012     A0
#  2:    Riverview  2013     A0
#  3:    Riverview  2014     A1
#  4: Lake Beach 1  2012     A2
#  5: Lake Beach 1  2012     A2
#  6: Lake Beach 2  2012     A3
#  7: Lake Beach 2  2013     A3
#  8: Lake Beach 2  2013     A3
#  9: Lake Beach 1  2013     A2
# 10:        Oasis  2012     A4
# 11:        Oasis  2013     A4
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@gregor-thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/903061/gregor-thomas), the following code does what I need (`.by` doesn't work with grouped dataframes so I've used `group_by()` instead:

```
data <- data %>%
group_by(AREA, YEAR) %>%
  mutate(
    AREA = case_when(
      n_distinct(ID) > 1 ~ paste(AREA, as.integer(factor(ID))),
      .default = AREA
    ),
  )
```